# Java Printing error toString() won't print

Tags: java

I  to created a class Card that models a regular playing card. In this class we are to create a toString() method to return a string representation of the card. We also had to create another class called CardTestDriver that prints out a specific card. I have written the code for the classes, but when I run it, nothing is printed. I am not sure what is wrong, it would be helpful if anyone could see where the error is? Everything is compiling, but not printing. This is also my first time using enum types so maybe I'm doing something wrong? Help would be much appreciated!

Here is my Card class:

```
public class Card{

   public enum Suit { 
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES; 
   }

   public enum Rank { 
       ACE, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, 
                   NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING
   }
   public enum Status {
    FACEUP, FACEDOWN
   }

  final Rank rank;
  final Suit suit;
  final Status status;

   public Card (final Rank rank, final Suit suit, final Status status) 
   {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.status = status;

   }

   public String toString()
   {
       return rank + " " + suit + " " + status;
   }

   }
```

Here is my CardTestDriver.java class

```
public class CardTestDriver{

    public void main(String[] args) { 

     new Card (Card.Rank.SEVEN,Card.Suit.SPADES,Card.Status.FACEDOWN);

     System.out.println(toString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try printing the actual instance of the card, `System.out.println(new Card (Card.Rank.SEVEN,Card.Suit.SPADES,Card.Status.FACEDOWN));` ...

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work - compiled, but nothing printed

Comment: Prints `SEVEN SPADES FACEDOWN` for me just fine

Comment: @onay - perhaps the issue is the lack of "static" declaration for the main method.  Are you running this class?  If so, the necessary method signature is `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: yes, and i also had tried that as well, but same result nothing printed

Answer (score 3):

You want to call the `toString` method of the card:

```
Card card = new Card (Card.Rank.SEVEN,Card.Suit.SPADES,Card.Status.FACEDOWN);
System.out.println(card.toString());
```

Comment: It's a static method, so you can't call `toString()` from `Object` without an instance. And `CardTestDriver` is never instantiated.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True. Answered a bit quickly :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - you are onto something here; the Op isn't calling toString() from static context; in fact, the main method isn't going to get used at all, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the actual object, something like `System.out.println(new Card(Card.Rank.SEVEN, Card.Suit.SPADES, Card.Status.FACEDOWN));` for example...

```
public class CardTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Card(Card.Rank.SEVEN, Card.Suit.SPADES, Card.Status.FACEDOWN));
    }

    public static class Card {

        public enum Suit {
            CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
        }

        public enum Rank {
            ACE, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT,
            NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING
        }

        public enum Status {
            FACEUP, FACEDOWN
        }

        final Rank rank;
        final Suit suit;
        final Status status;

        public Card(final Rank rank, final Suit suit, final Status status) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;
            this.status = status;

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return rank + " " + suit + " " + status;
        }

    }
}
```

This prints `SEVEN SPADES FACEDOWN` to the console just fine