# Enums in java: How can I use numbers

Tags: java, enums

I am working on a program with deck of cards. Currently I have:

```
public enum Numbers {
    N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10, JACK, KING, QUEEN, ACE
}
```

I really need to display them as actual numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc because I am trying to make my program more readable.
I tried using a toString method like this but it doesn't really change anything:

```
N2 {

    public String toString() {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: `TWO`, `THREE`, `FOUR`, etc?

Comment: Agreed with @Phil. And if you want to manipulate actual integer, please consider [adding an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054272/4906586)

Comment: When you say actual numbers, do you want JACK, KING, QUEEN, ACE, to show up as 11, 12, 13, 1 ?

Comment: No, i would keep the JACK, KING, QUEEN and ACE either as they are or as J, K, Q, A

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758977/how-to-display-cards-in-a-card-game-in-java-and-have-them-clickable-for-selectio/48760120#48760120) (dig a little it's in there) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468982/java-printing-error-tostring-wont-print/32470422#32470422)

Comment: So return `name().startsWith("N") ? name().substring(1) : name().substring(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass whatever `int` value you want for each `enum` value in the constructor and at declaration time. And then use that in your `toString()` method. Like,

```
public enum Numbers {
    N2(2), N3(3), N4(4), N5(5), N6(6), N7(7), N8(8), N9(9), 
            N10(10), JACK(11), KING(12), QUEEN(13), ACE(1);
    Numbers(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private int value;

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass String to the constructor instead of converting the value each time. Maybe you don’t even need to pass value, simply set this.valueStr = Integer.toString(ordinal());.